# Error occurs while calling Instagram user API. Just died in GET Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, instagram-api

I am working on Instagram User API. 'self' API works fine, but '{user_id}' does not work.

Here is their API DOC. https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

This is my ajax code to get user information.

```
function setInstagramLogin(btnId, userId){
    var target = document.getElementById(btnId);
    var user = (userId == null || typeof userId == 'undefined') ? 'self' : userId;
    target.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var loginUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + user + '/?callback=?';
        console.log(loginUrl);
        $.getJSON(loginUrl, access_parameters, function(instagramData){
            console.log(instagramData);
            var userInfo = instagramData.data;
            alert('Your Information\n username [ ' + userInfo.username + ' ]\n'
                    + 'profile Photo [ ' + userInfo.profile_picture + ' ]\n');
        });

    }, false);
}
```

And from jsp, I call like ...

```
setInstagramLogin('loginBtn');
setInstagramLogin('loginBtn', 'jygood');
```

The first one, call 'self' works, the other does not.
How can I fix this?

The error happens inside of callback jQuery I guess.
Here is chrome inspector error

> GET
>   https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/jygood/?callback=jQuery21109406823019962…s_token=211611405.1677ed0.4e0e854196454874b858e21c293b919d&_=1450936187539
>
> send @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
>
> n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
>
> n.(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
>
> n.extend.getJSON @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous function) @ instagram.js:29

line29 is `$.getJSON()` part of first script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `+ user +` should be an `id` not instagram `username`

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/jygood/?callback=
```

looks like you are using `jygood` username instead of `user_id`, it should be an integer value

Comment: Thanks! I was a dumb :D b